# Is Rails going "backwards" in the code in this example?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I have following html page `home.html.erb`:

```
<% provide(:title, 'Home') %>

<h1>Sample App</h1>
<p>
  This is the home page for the
  <a href="http://railstutorial.org/">Ruby on Rails Tutorial</a>
  sample application.
</p>
```

And I have the following layout `application.html.erb`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>

        ...

</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

`full_title()` is a function that checks if there was a title passed as a parameter. If there was, it will place it into the HTML. If no parameter is given, it will place a base title into the HTML.

I'm assuming rails begins by going through the `application.html.erb` and then upon reaching `<%= yield %>`, it will embed the contents of `home.html.erb` into `application.html.erb` at that location, resulting in the following document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>

        ...

</head>
<body>

<% provide(:title, 'Home') %>

<h1>Sample App</h1>
<p>
  This is the home page for the
  <a href="http://railstutorial.org/">Ruby on Rails Tutorial</a>
  sample application.
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

In the 4th line `<%= full_title(yield(:title)) %>`, the value "Home" is definitely being passed for `:title`, but the code `<% provide(:title, 'Home') %>` doesn't come until several lines later. Is Rails going backwards to accomplish this? How is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

No it's don't. This is kind of string interpolation, this value will be replaced after every call of provide(:title, ...)

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that the home.html.erb is processed before the application layout. In other words, the view and helper are prepared and 'plugged-in' to the application layout before the whole thing is complete. I guess "going backwards" depends on which way you look at it / how it actually works. I'm still learning too, but it's not necessarily a 'top to bottom' sequence in terms of how the code is layed out on the page.